# Convert month part of date to short name mysql 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

*date_format* converts the current date to the selected format

```
select date_format(now(),'%d-%M-%Y');
```

result is

```
'29-November-2020'
```

Is there a function that can give me `29-Nov-2020` ? I could see this being done by converting the month to number and using case & concat statements, but will probably be overly complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) say use `%b`

```
select date_format(now(),'%d-%b-%Y');
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/186853)